# Assembly two-dimensional array of pixels

Tags: arrays, assembly, pixel

How could I do something like this in assembly? DOS 16bit graphic mode

```
int start_x=1, start_y=1;
for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<8; j++){
        if(T34[i][j]==1) put_colour_pixel(start_x+i, start_y+j);
        else put_black_pixel(start_x+i, start_y+j);
    }
}
```

---

:edit:

So my loops pretty work. How to connect it to table with 0 and 1.

```
mov ax, 10 ; Y start line
    mov bx, 20 ; X start line
    mov dl, 4  ; colour (red)
    mov cx, 5 ; loop top counter
    top:
        add ax, 1
        push cx ;loop top counter
        mov cx, 10
        inside:
        add bx, 1

        push ax
        push bx
        push cx

        call putpixel

        pop cx
        pop bx
        pop ax
        loop inside
        mov bx, 20 ;next line X go to start X

        pop cx ;loop top counter

    loop top
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
My new code:

```
    segment .data

    segment .code
..start:
    mov ax, 13h 
    int 10h               ; switch to 320x200 mode

    mov ax, 0a000h        ; The offset to video memory
    mov es, ax            ; We load it to ES through AX,
                          ; because immediate operation
                          ; is not allowed on ES

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

       mov di, T34
       mov si, 8
;------------------------------------
P1:    mov bp, 8

;----------------
P2:    cmp BYTE[di], 1
       jnz short NOHIT

NOHIT: ; increase the x position

        push ax
       push bx
       push cx
       mov ax,si ;Y
       mov bx,bp ;X
       mov dl, 1 ; here I should take '0' or '1' from table
       call putpixel
       pop cx
       pop bx
       pop ax

       inc di  ; increase offset address of array
       dec bp
       jnz P2
;-------------
       ; increase the y position + substract 8 from x position
       dec si
       jnz P1
;------------------------------------


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

    xor ah, ah
    int 16h               ; keyboard (wait for key)

    mov ax, 3
    int 10h               ; go to text mode

    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h               ; return to DOS, exit code 0

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

putpixel:
    push dx               ; mul changes dx too
    mov cx, 320
    mul cx                ; multiply Y (ax) by 320 (one row)
    add ax, bx            ; and add X (bx) (result= dx:ax)
    mov di, ax
    pop dx
    mov [es:di], dl       ; store color/pixel
    ret

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

T34 DB 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
    DB 1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    DB 1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    DB 1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    DB 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
    DB 1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    DB 1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    DB 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
```

I have changed order and now it is drawing square in left corner (as I expected). Did I change order rigth?
I suppose that letter will be spinned, but it is not problem for me. I can fix it later.

Now I should go to '0' or '1' in table and set color. Which register have "0" or "1"?

So mostly I have problem with colour.
I have try this, but I have error. I have try set colour black (0) or blue (1)

```
 push dx
   mov ax, bp ; X*8
   mov cx,8
   mul cx
   add ax, si ; X*8 +Y

   add ax, di ; tab0 + X*8+Y

   mov dl,  ax; here is error, here I set the colour
   pop dx
```

So I don't know how to fix it :( I have try different possibilities and northing work.

Comment: "... variables. Where should I store..."  use registers. faster to work on, easier addressable.

Comment: I would try, but I am not sure is enough regiters to store firstly start x, start y, loop count( for in for is good way or is another?), pixel x, pixel y. What about array? How could I access to this? Or maybe should I use 32 bit to this? I'm sorry for that much questions, but I'm just started

Comment: Be economic with register use. Stack those registers which aren't accessed frequently, to free them for alternative use.

Comment: I edited my question. When my one loop will work I will try do another inside. What is wrong in this piece of code?

Comment: your putpixel routine modifies ax register

Comment: Why don't you let a C compiler generate the assembly output for you? Then you can use it as working example and strip/modify it as you like. Begin with compiler optimization switched off.

Comment: Hmm because my teacher will read my code and I think he will not accept compiler generate code. Now when I have two loops how can I connect it with array? My task is to write sinus text scroll, but firstly I need to learn how put letter in graphic mode.

Comment: No register contains "0" or "1" with this compare instruction "cmp BYTE[di],1", we only check the content of the address if it is 1 and the result will be notify in the zero flag of the flag-register. And Now we can use it with a following conditional jump instruction just before another instruction is modifying the zeroflag again.

Comment: For the outerloop the Y-coordinate goes to Y + 7 upwards in the vertical direction. The innerloop start from X and goes to X + 7 moving right sideways in the horizontal direction. And we set the pixel line by line.

Comment: But the loop counters goes from 8 to 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
       mov di, T34
       mov si, 8
;------------------------------------
P1:    mov bp, 8
;----------------
P2:    cmp BYTE[di], 1
       jnz short NOHIT

       ; save used REGISTER
       ; load register with the X,Y position and color
       call putpixel
       ; get back the saved Register

NOHIT: ; increase the x position
       inc di  ; increase offset address of array
       dec bp  ; decrease counter and set zeroflag if register is zero
       jnz P2  ; jump if zeroflag is not set
;-------------
       ; increase the y position + substract 8 from x position
       dec si
       jnz P1
;------------------------------------
```

It is also possible to start the counters for the loops with 0 for to increase the counter, but then we need a compare instruction for to leave the loop, if we want to run the loop from 0 to 8. The offset addresses inside of the array are pointed independent with no relationship to the counters.

With a little modifying (put an additional jump instruction in the code and a second call) it is also possible to set a black pixel if the byte of the array is 0. But i think this simple form of a nested loop is easier to understand in the first time.

Edit: Now it is compatible for NASM.

---

Edit2: Maybe it is more simple to store the x,y coordinates into a known ram location for modifying and reloading inside of a loop, if many parameters are in use.

Our ram location:

```
Color DB ?  ; define byte
X_Pos DW ?  ; define word
Y_Pos DW ?
```

Examples for to show how to access a memory location (default segment is DS):

```
mov [X_Pos], ax
mov [X_Pos], bx  
mov [Color], dl  
mov ax, [X_Pos]
mov bx, [Y_Pos]
mov dl, [Color]

mov WORD[X_Pos], 10
inc WORD[X_Pos]
sub WORD[X_Pos], 8
mov BYTE[Color], 4
inc BYTE[Color]
```

---

Edit3:

```
mov dl,  ax; here is error, here I set the colour
```

It is not possible to mix an 8 bit register with a 16 Bit register.
Note:

```
AX = AL+AH
DX = DL+DH
```

Existing instruction are:

```
mov dl,  al
mov dl,  ah
mov dx,  ax
movzx dl, ax
```

Comment: This line:  mov di, OFFSET T34 and this: P2:    cmp BYTE PTR[di], 1 shows me that sth is expected after operand. I don't know why. So I couldn't compile it. I use nasm 16 DOS.

Comment: For NASM remove "OFFSET" and remove "PTR", its only for MASM.

Comment: It is good Y and X? mov ax, si ;Y
    mov bx, bp ;X
                   like 'i' and 'j' in language C?

Comment: It don't work. Even if I try put single pixel, for example 10,10. It only enter to P1 loop, to P2 not.

Comment: Please post all of your new code and let us see what is happend.

Comment: The new code is missing to "; increase the y position + substract 8 from the x position". This can be done with manipulating the position in an register, or with manipulating the position in a memory location, if we are reloading the coordinates from this location before we set a pixel.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I really don't know how to set colour. I try and edit post, but it is still not working :(